# How can a “stocking suspender” sharpen a razor?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, american-english

In Mark Twain's short story "[About Barbers](https://americanliterature.com/author/mark-twain/short-story/about-barbers)" it says

> He finished lathering, and then began to rub in the suds with his hand.
>
> He now began to **sharpen his razor on an old suspender**, and was delayed a good deal on account of a controversy…

But Cambridge Dictionary says "a long piece of elastic that hangs down from a suspender belt and holds a stocking up" for *suspender*.
I could not understand how to sharpen a razor on it. Is there an idiom for it?

Comment: There is a difference in AmE and BrE usage. In BrE a *suspender* holds up the stockings (underwear), and *braces* hold up the trousers (pants).

Comment: And in AmE a device which holds up a lady's *stockings* is called a *garter*. Since Mark Twain was an American, it would be better to use an American English dictionary (such as Merriam-Webster, at merriam-webster.com) when reading his works. This is especially true for words which refer to the everyday objects and features of the local environment. These include the names of foods, clothing, tools, the parts of an automobile, features of roads, and to some extent furniture.

Comment: The critical point to understand is that **they were leather straps** in those days.  (Which is precisely what you sharpen a blade on .. a strop.)  You would "translate" this to "belt" these days - which are more obviously leather.

Comment: Welcome HuseyinKilic  - very simply, read through to the next meaning in the dictionary.  In English it's really common that words have a huge number of totally different meanings.

Comment: @Fattie you would still need to know that "suspenders/braces" were of leather and that's not mentioned in the C.Dict.

Comment: While the reformatting of the question is useful, I think the insertion of "stocking suspender" rather than just "suspender" in the title is not. The literal answer to the title of the question now is, "It cannot."

Comment: You might want to remove the word "stocking" from your title, since it isn't in the quote (or readily inferred from the question) and as @David42 pointed out, that isn't the meaning that Twain would have been using. He would have been using meaning 2(a) [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspender): *"one of two supporting bands worn across the shoulders to support trousers, skirt, or belt —usually used in plural and often with pair"*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the terms suspender belt, and stocking were the OP's. Their confusion stems from the research they did. The title is, admittedly, slightly clickbaity but it does not misrepresent the OP's reason for asking.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I know. I was addressing the OP. Regardless of their misunderstanding, the title is misleading. The misunderstanding can be addressed in the text.

Answer (score 25):

Nowadays a suspender (AmE) is elastic.  In those days a suspender was likely to be a pair of leather straps that clipped onto your pants (AmE) and over your shoulders. They are still available, for people wanting to have an "old world cowboy" style.

[image]

You can sharpen a razor blade on leather. A razor needs to be sharpened very finely so the final honing stage is done with leather. The point of the quote is that the barber isn't using a dedicated sharpening strop, but is using a piece of leather that was designed for another purpose.

Comment: When you said *strap* did you mean [*strop*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/strop?s=t)?

Comment: In reality it's not a *sharpening* process but rather an edge straightening - similar to a butcher using a steel on a knife.

Comment: And I always thought "stroppy" and "strop" were slang meaning someone with a negative attitude, bad tempered and unwilling to cooperate. Who knew it was a wide leather strip.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - hmm, that's really interesting you have not heard the common word "strop", knowing you!  Perhaps it is some unique combination of interests, or something.

Comment: i didn't actually realize that, @Trunk , thanks!  honing is like "a tune-up, not quite sharpening, little if any material removed"

Comment: The edit **is wrong**.  There's no such thing as a "dedicated sharpening strop".  It would be like saying "turning it with, a dedicated screwdriver".  You can say "turning it with, a dedicated tool" (meaning a screwdriver) but "a dedicated screwdriver" is wrong.  The sentence should read "a dedicated sharpening strap", or, "a strop".

Comment: @Fattie Could the strop not be dedicated to the barbershop, as opposed to dedicated to sharpening only? Barbershops in the past have had strops built into the counters. So that would be a strop that is physically dedicated to the barbershop.

Comment: lol excellent point @ToddWilcox !!

Comment: @Fattie: Why do you claim “a dedicated sharpening stop” or “a dedicated screwdriver” is wrong?  “He unscrewed it with the edge of a dime, instead of a dedicated screwdriver.”  It’s *redundant*, certainly, but not wrong — pleonasm for emphasis is a classic rhetorical device. At most, it is arguably bad style; but at least to my ear, this is exactly the kind of example where it works well and serves a genuine purpose, pointing up the relevant aspect of the strop/strap distinction.

Comment: Hi @PLL  - it's a typo for "strap", since a "dedicated strap" *is* a "strop".  (Of course, ANY time in language something is "wrong", from spelling to tempo, one can say "oh, blah blah, usage, style etc".)  Note that the example you give is literally an example of where you *would* say "dedicated screwdriver".  (In my comment, I was literally going to *give that example*, saying "Oh, in other situations of course you would use dedicated screwdriver." But there was no room. And there's no more room here.)

Comment: @Trunk I hope your comment gets edited in to the answer (or make your own). I've seen these used in countless films and tv shows and never ever understood how leather of any type can sharpen a knife. Makes so much more sense that it straightens the edge!

Comment: I believe the post may be read in good faith as-is, as "a dedicated [piece of leather taking the form of a] sharpening strop", which seems entirely correct to me.

Comment: @Fattie If you have a screw with an unusually sized or shaped head (such as an [odd-pointed star-head screw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentalobe_security_screw)), then that will require a dedicated screwdriver, rather than a generic flat-head or phillips-head screwdriver

Comment: @Chronocidal .  Heh, as I literally just typed: the example **you just gave** is literally an example of where you **would** say "dedicated screwdriver". In my original discussion, I was literally going to give such an example, saying "Oh, in other situations of course you **would** use dedicated screwdriver."

Answer (score 16):

This is tricky even for a native speaker, as it depends on knowing how straight razors are used. It used to be common to go to a barber to get a shave with a straight razor. Now most people use disposable razors, and so knowing how to sharpen a razor is no longer common knowledge.

As the final step of sharpening a razor, a [strop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Razor_strop) is used to polish and straighten the edge:

[image]
[Dr.K. 15:35, 4 November 2007 (UTC)](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Razor_and_strop.JPG) / [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)

A strop is often leather, sometimes with a little abrasive on it. Since a razor must be very sharp to cut hair, it is usually stropped before every shave.

*Suspenders* may be elastic like your dictionary says, but in the time of the story, probably leather was more common. Also suspenders may not hold up only stockings, but also pants. For American English (all Twain stories will use American English) "suspenders" will mean something holding up pants, like these [modern leather suspenders from Colonel Littleton](https://www.colonellittleton.com/shop/no-2-adjustable-leather-suspenders-snap-hook/):

[image]

The leather straps from suspenders like this could be made into a strop, and that's what the barber was doing.

Comment: I don't think the leather braces shown in your photo are functional. 1. They look slack 2. The wearer has an adequate recess above his pelvic girdle to provide a "hold" for his pants without any braces. 3. Guys needing braces for trousers support need a degree of elastication on the braces so that their nuts are not cut in half while their pants is still high enough. Leather without any elastic section will not allow this.

Comment: @Trunk Good points, I'll notify Colonel Littleton.

Comment: *His needs were few, his room was bare: / A lavabo and a fancy chair / A mug of suds and a leather strop / An apron, a towel, a pail and a mop / For neatness he deserved a nod / Did Sweeney Todd / The demon barber of Fleet Street*

Answer (score 3):

This is the [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/suspender) entry for suspender:

> suspender
> noun
> UK  /səˈspen.dər/ US  /səˈspen.dɚ/
> [ C ] UK
> **(US garter)**
> a long piece of elastic that hangs down from a suspender belt and holds a stocking up suspenders [ plural ]
> **US (UK braces)
> a pair of narrow straps that stretch from the front of the trousers over your shoulders to the back to hold them up**

I've bolded the important parts. The "US garter" says that this is not the meaning in the US; this meaning is referred to as a garter in the US. The last part tells you what the word means in the US. It's important to pay attention to notes on regional variations such as these, and not stop reading after just one meaning has been given. If one meaning doesn't seem to fit a passage, you should see whether there are alternative meanings, paying especial attention to meanings for the region in which the work was written.

Comment: Even if I knew that (US) suspenders were the same as (UK) braces, I wouldn't have known two things: 1. That suspenders used to be made of leather. Who knew? My father, class 1924, wore [elastic braces with metal clips](https://www.google.com/search?q=trousers+braces+%22metal+clips%22&sxsrf=ALeKk01wRNtTh2Zv4WWCUoBUQsHK5iHPKQ:1602680936849&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN_Lbfk7TsAhVGNOwKHRrhBlEQ_AUoAXoECAQQAw&biw=1274&bih=647) 2. That people used to sharpen a blade on a leather strap. I thought it was either stone/whetstone, honing steel/butcher's steel or a grinding wheel

Comment: @Mari-LouA You can probably find a movie western with a barbershop scene where the barber sharpens his razor on a leather strap.

Comment: @Barmar My dad’s barber included a straight razor shave with every haircut, and he used a leather strop too. But it is definitely less common since the advent of the disposable safety razor people can use at home.

Comment: Since AIDS, barbers only use razors with disposable blades, so sharpening "fixed blade" razors is now obsolete. Sharpening precision cutting tools on leather is still common - whetstones or grinding wheels are too abrasive. A stone is good enough to sharpen a scythe, but not a scalpel.

Comment: @alephzero source? There are some shops around where I live that have straight razor shaves. (Pretty rare yes, but the practice isn't gone)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: There is a difference between honing a blade and sharpening it.  If a sharp blade is used to cut across something (as a straight razor would be), the thinnest parts of the blade will get bent out of true.  The further out of true they are, the more they will get bent.  The bent blade will still be sharp, but it will cease to cut evenly.  Honing a blade straightens it while removing a minimal amount of material.  By contrast, sharpening a blade entails removing material from a blade with a blunt edge so as to make it sharp.